# Unable to start SQL Server 2008 service

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2, and I am having an issue with my local server instance.  At first, this only happened occasionally and seemingly completely randomly, but was fixed when I restarted my computer.  Now, however, it's a constant problem.

When I try to connect to my server through the management studio, I am unable to connect with the message saying that the "server cannot be found or is not accessible".  Sometimes when this happens, I am able to open my Sql Server Configuration Manager, and can quickly find and start my local instance, and I'm good to go.  However, lately, I have frequently been unable to find the server, and instead of showing a number of items in the list, I am only seeing two Sql Server Integration Services items.

When I check in the Services.msc, I can find the correct service, SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER2008), but when I try to start it, I get an error stating that "Windows could not start the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER2008) service on Local Computer. Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."  As a side note: I am also getting this same error when trying to start the Virtual Disk service, and can not access my Disk Management.

When I try to start the service from the command line (by going to the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER2008\MSSQL\Binn` and executing `sqlservr.exe`), it eventually causes an error stating that SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit has stopped working, and gives me the option to close the program.  Checking the event viewer log yields this:

> Windows cannot access the file C:\Windows\System32\netapi32.dll for
>   one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network
>   connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage
>   drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows
>   closed the program SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit because of this
>   error.
>
> Program: SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit File:
>   C:\Windows\System32\netapi32.dll
>
> The error value is listed in the Additional Data section. User
>   Action
>   1. Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again.
>   2. If the file still cannot be accessed and
>     - It is on the network, your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem with the network and that the server can be
>   contacted.
>     - It is on a removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the disk is fully inserted into the computer.
>   3. Check and repair the file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run, type CMD, and then click OK. At the command
>   prompt, type CHKDSK /F, and then press ENTER.
>   4. If the problem persists, restore the file from a backup copy.
>   5. Determine whether other files on the same disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard disk, contact your
>   administrator or computer hardware vendor for further assistance.
>
> Additional Data Error value: C0000185 Disk type: 3

I have verified that the file `C:\Windows\System32\netapi32.dll` exists on the drive, file version `6.1.7601.17514`.  I have run `CHKDSK` and `sfc /SCANNOW` and it returned that it did not find any integrity violations.   I have also checked the drive for malware and viruses doing a full system scan with both Malwarebytes and Norton Antivirus.

Obviously I'd rather not have to reinstall SQL Server or worse, format the drive and reinstall everything.  I am also in the unfortunate situation of not having my windows 7 cd.  Please help!

Comment: Not being able to open disk management can be a symptom of a malware infection. Have you scanned your computer for viruses? Malwarebytes and SuperAntiSpyware might pick up something your virus scanner doesn't.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the response.  I just installed and ran a full system scan using Malwarebytes and after two hours it found nothing wrong.  I have also run a full scan using my Norton, and it found nothing as well.  I installed SUPERAntiSpyware and when I try to run it I'm getting an error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000006). Click OK to close the application.

Comment: Has there been any recent changes to the system or has it been wonky from the start?

Comment: It's mostly been gradually getting worse, I think as the C drive has gotten closer to full.  After the current situation got as bad as it is, I went through and cleared out space on drive C hoping to improve it, and it now has just over 26 GB free, but it didn't improve.  Also, the battery is a little loose and sometimes it disconnects when the computer is in sleep mode, and gives me the message that windows didn't shut down properly, and gives me the option to start it in safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

(As the thread has been moved to serverfault and I don't have sufficient rep here to add a comment, I'll have to reply in an answer.)

You really should **make a full backup** of your disk(s) to an external drive as soon as possible, preferably while using a mains power adapter. The battery being loose could affect the power to the computer even while it's using the power adapter, so be sure not to move it when you're doing the backup, preferably don't even touch it, and check the power saving mode so it won't try sleeping or shutting down at an inopportune moment.

Then **get the battery connection mended**. You cannot reasonably expect software to run reliably on unreliable hardware. It is conceivable that it presents a fire hazard as there will be a high current flowing through the resistance of a loose connector, so you may want to avoid leaving it unattended. Please don't be alarmed, just be sensible.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I know the battery issue needs to be fixed... However, that will not fix the problem I'm having getting my sql server fired up